# TCP test client returning not expected tuple

Tags: python, tcp

```
import socket

def client():
    ip = input('type and send ip address to connect to: ')
host = socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)
port = 8080

s = socket.socket()
s.connect((host, port))

username = input('type and send your username: ')
while True:
    message = input()
    if message == 'q':
        break
    message = username + '> ' + message
    s.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
    data = s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
    print(data)
s.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client()
```

I'm creating a messaging client and I'm creating the client part of it, unfortunately I've encountered an issue, where I do `socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)` it thinks that the `ip` variable is a `tuple`, and I'm not even sure what that is, I haven't found any people with the same issue as me.

Error when typing and sending IP Address:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Checken\Desktop\messaging client test\client.py", line 23, in <module>
    client()
  File "C:\Users\Checken\Desktop\messaging client test\client.py", line 9, in client
    s.connect((host, port))
TypeError: str, bytes or bytearray expected, not tuple
```

Comment: You must have some global `ip` variable that *is* a tuple (although its definition is not shown in the code in your question). Note that the `ip` variable in the `client()` function is a local variable (i.e. not visible outside the function).

Comment: This is my full code.

Comment: In that case, your description of the issue is unclear. If there's an error message or exception being generated, please add it to the question.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: The problem is exactly what the error message indicates: You're passing `(host, port)` (a `tuple`) as the argument to `socket.connect()`, which is expecting a "str, bytes or bytearray`.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you.

Comment: Note that what I said earlier about `ip` being a local variable in the `client()` function still applies.